# Poisson distribution formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The formula $\frac{\lambda^x\cdot e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$ represents a probability, so it is clearly less than or equal to 1. But this is not immediately clear from the formula itself. Is there an easy way of proving this fact?

Thnx

Comment: I suppose that "x" is an integer. Is it ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $p(x)=\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}=\Bbb{P}(X=x)$ is a discrete p.d.f. (Poisson pdf) and $p(x)\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$ and observing that
$$
\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}=e^{\lambda}
$$
you have
$$
\sum_{x=0}^\infty p(x)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}=e^{\lambda}e^{-\lambda}=1
$$
(i.e. $p(x)$ is a pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Sum over $k$ ($x$ in your case) and obtain $1$. Clearly each term $\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{k!}>0$. If at most one out of infinite set of terms was greater than 1, the sum would be greater that 1. From this it follows that $0<\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{k!}<1$.